# Basing modeling of a holder

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model this simple thing. Anyone have any idea how to do model this. Without the top black. I tried to do this but the half of the mesh looks different.

[image]

Comment: Please use the "edit" button and add an image or sketch of what you'd like to model.

Comment: If you are using a Mirror Modifier it looks like there maybe faces inside the mesh where it meets in the middle.

Comment: No it is not mirror. I duplicate and bridge faces.

Comment: The half of the mesh looks different because normals are inverted there. If you modeled it manually in Edit mode select all and Ctrl+N. If you used Mirror modifier try applying scale first and then the same with normals

Answer (score 3):

One approach:

Make sure the cursor is centered SHIFT + “C”
Add a Plane
TAB into Edit Mode
Subdivide the Plane press “W” > Subdivide

[image: Subdivided Plane]

Delete one half

[image: Half Plane]

Add a Mirror Modifier and check the box next to “Clipping”

[image: Mirror Modifier]

Select all of the vertices and press “S” + “Y” (in top view) to scale on the y axis only.

[image: Scale]

Select the edge and extrude up by pressing “E” + “Z” and Left Mouse Click to accept

[image: Extrude Up]

Press “G” + “X” and grab the edge inward (I exaggerated this)

[image: Angle]

Place the cursor near the edge and press ALT + “R” to create a radius. You can adjust the radius in the operator panel “Before” you do anything else.

[image: Radius]

Press “E” + “X” and extrude to the center

[image: Extrude]

Add a Solidify Modifier and adjust the thickness to taste

[image: Solidify]

Comment: How did you create the radius please?

Comment: @ Evripidis Yuri Gazetis - In Front View place the Cursor next to the edge. Blender will create the radius around the Cursor. Pressing ALT + "R" will generate the radius. You can adjust the parameters in the operator panel on the left (Pressing "T" toggles the Tool Panel ) but need to do that BEFORE doing anything else. Look at the 7th image for reference. 
 https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/spin.html

Comment: Thanks but now i have this problem. The radius created from left to right and there is no spin menu in tool side panel.

Comment: @ Evripidis Yuri Gazetis - Pressing "T" toggles the Tool pane on and off. The Spin portion is only available immediately after you press ALT + "R" and should be at the bottom of the "Tool Tab". Change the Angle to positive or negative to change the direction of the radius.

Comment: @ Evripidis Yuri Gazetis - Heres a detailed easy to follow tutorial https://vimeo.com/44841561